# Cannot find the indicated Syntax Error in my Smarty template

Tags: smarty

I am getting the following error when I call an ajax function

```
SmartyCompilerException: Syntax Error in template "themes/themename/ajax-product-sort.tpl" on line 16 "<option value="{$link->addSortDetails($request, 'price', 'asc')|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" {if $orderby eq 'price' AND $orderway eq 'ASC' }selected="selected"{/if>l} {s='price: lowest first'}</option>" - Unexpected " }" in D:\wamp\www\sitename\tools\smarty\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php on line 431
```

and i cand find any syntax mistake on that particular line

```
<option value="{$link->addSortDetails($request, 'price', 'asc')|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" {if $orderby eq 'price'    AND $orderway eq 'ASC' }selected="selected"{/if}>{l s='price: lowest first'}</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

In smarty you address objects and arrays with ".", not "->".

So I would try

```
{$link.addSortDetails($request, 'price', 'asc')|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}
```